# Extents of rotated OpenLayers3 map

Tags: openlayers, extents

https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/rotation.html is an example of a rotated map. If I take the extents of that, they do not reference the actual corners of the displayed map area but something prior(?) to rotation.

How do I get the actual extents or corner coordinates of a rotated map?

To see/reproduce the issue, you can copy and paste this into the browser console after loading above example and then zoom out.

```
var extents = map.getView().calculateExtent(map.getSize());
var poly_extents = ol.geom.Polygon.fromExtent(extents);

var p = new ol.layer.Vector({
  source: new ol.source.Vector({
      features: [new ol.Feature({
          geometry: poly_extents,
      })]
  }),
});

map.addLayer(p);
```

[image: Extents of rotated map, shown after zooming out]

Answer (score 1):

An incredibly awkward and terrible way would be getting the coordinates of the outmost pixels via screen coordinates like this:

```
// from https://stackoverflow.com/a/11744120/4828720 , no idea if safe
var w = window,
    d = document,
    e = d.documentElement,
    g = d.getElementsByTagName('body')[0],
    x = w.innerWidth || e.clientWidth || g.clientWidth,
    y = w.innerHeight|| e.clientHeight|| g.clientHeight;

var topleft = map.getCoordinateFromPixel([0,0]);
var topright = map.getCoordinateFromPixel([x,0]);
var bottomleft = map.getCoordinateFromPixel([0,y]);
var bottomright = map.getCoordinateFromPixel([x,y]);
```

From there you could go on and create a Polygon or whatever:

```
var corner_coordinates = [topleft, topright, bottomright, bottomleft, topleft];
var bounding_geometry = new ol.geom.Polygon([coordinates]);
```